# A struct that captures variables in its function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

Is it possible to build the struct

```rust
struct MyFn<A, B> {
    call: fn(A) -> B
}
```

such that it's able to capture immutable variables like in the following snippet?

```rust
let y: &f64 = &3.0
let my_fn: MyFn<f64, f64> {
    call: |x| {
        x + *y
    }
}
```

I'm aware that a closure is needed in this case, but what should the type of `call` be so that it can capture any immutable reference (e.g. a function reference)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to build the struct[...] such that it's able to capture...?

No - capturing involves a closure, and the type of `MyFn::call` is a function. `MyFn` can store a closure in `call` by either making its type generic type or a trait object.

A generic is perfectly efficient, but makes `MyFn` have a different type for each closure:

```
struct MyFn<A, B, F: Fn(A) -> B> {
    call: F,
    _data: PhantomData<(A, B)>,
}

let y: f64 = 3.0;
let my_fn: MyFn<f64, f64, _> = MyFn {
    call: |x| x + y,
    _data: PhantomData,
};
```

Having separate types for each closure means that you won't be able to easily create a vector of `MyFn`s with different closures, or store it in a place where you need to spell out the type.

Alternatively, you can make `call` *dynamic*, i.e. express it as a trait object. That will keep `MyFn` generic only over the input and output type, and will prevent different closures from affecting the type of `MyFn`. This flexibility comes at the cost of an allocation when constructing `MyFn` and a pointer indirection when invoking `call`. (That cost in advance is not nearly as large as it's sometimes made out to be, but it's good to be aware of it.) Such `MyFn` looks like this:

```
struct MyFn<'a, A, B> {
    call: Box<dyn Fn(A) -> B + 'a>,
}

let y: f64 = 3.0;
let my_fn: MyFn<f64, f64> = MyFn {
    call: Box::new(|x| x + y),
};
```

The dynamic version appears to have an extra lifetime compared to the generic one, but that's because the lifetime was part of the unnamed type of the closure in the previous version.